# How to redirect to lowercase when specific url contains at least one capital letter

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to redirect all possible combinations of lower/uppercase url to lowercase, but only for one specific url `example-url`.

Sample:

`/eXample-url => /example-url
/Example-Url => /example-url
/examPle-URL => /example-url`

`RewriteRule ^example-url(.*)$ /example-url$1 [NC,R=301,L]` cause redirect loop...

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lookahead to make sure at least one uppercase letter is there with `(?i)` flag to make it ignore-case after lookahead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?i)example-url(/.*)?$ /example-url$1 [R=302,L]
```

- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])` is a **positive lookahead** to ensure there is at least one uppercase letter.
- `(?i)` is for making rest of pattern ignore case.

**An alternative without lookahead:**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule ^example-url(/.*)?$ /example-url$1 [R=302,L,NC]
```

Comment: Perfect. This is what I was looking for, but without NC flag. Thanks!